# Angular does not update page when an a-tag is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a tab navigation from twitter bootstrap that I'm using to navigate my page.
[image]

When I click on `tournaments` the view doesn't update, but the url now shows `#/tournaments`:

[image]
[image]

But if I click on the url bar, and hit enter, it changes the view:

[image]

I have set up the project with a build folder and a compiled folder. When the project is in the build folder, everything works fine. Then I use grunt to concat and minify files, and put it in the compiled folder, and that is when it starts to act like this.

I use `r.js` for concatination and minification (I'm using `require.js`) and I get no errors during the process. All the html views are also copied over correctly, as you see when I force refresh the browser window.

It is like angular doesn't react to the change in location, but the `active-tab`, the one with its title in gray, gets swapped around correctly. It is just the view that doesn't update.

Does anyone know what this can be?

I have put the tabs in its own directive:

```
define(['angular'], function (ng) {
var directives = ng.module('directives', []);

/* top navigation tabs */
directives.directive('tabset', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-transclude></ul>'
    };
})
.directive('tab', ['$location', function ($location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            route: '@',
            title: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var route = attrs.route;

            scope.location = $location;
            scope.active = false;

            scope.$watch('location.path()', function (new_route) {
                scope.active = route === new_route;
            });
        },
        template: '<li data-ng-class="{active: active}">' +
                    '<a href="#{{route}}">{{title}}</a>' +
                    '</li>'
    };
}]);

return directives;
});
```

I use it like this:

```
<tabset>
    <tab data-route="/home" data-title="Home"></tab>
    <tab data-route="/tournaments" data-title="Tournaments"></tab>
    <tab data-route="/about" data-title="About"></tab>
</tabset>
```

The problem occurs after minification and concatination.

EDIT: It seems like it doesn't load all the sources:

In the `build` path:

[image]

In the `compiled`path:

[image]

When I click on one of the links in the `build` path, a http GET request is sent for the view I need, this does not happen in the `compile` path.

`.../build/#/...` works.
`.../compiled/#/...` does not work.

Comment: did you try to use ng-href instead of href?

Comment: It gives the same results as `href`.

Comment: try with `$location.path()` in `ng-click` like `ng-click='$location.path(YourUrl)'`

Comment: @Satpal I can't get `$location.path({{route}})` to work. Trying like this: `'<a ng-click="$location.path({{route}})">{{title}}</a>'` and
`'<a ng-click="' + $location.path('{{route}}') + '">{{title}}</a>'`. None of them prints the url.

Comment: It just tries to navigate to `compiled/$location(/home)` (or any other route).